# Google Coral Accelerator Module + Microcontroller

Tags: google-coral

Is it possible to use microcontroller (e.g. STM32) as a host for Coral accelerator module? It seems to me that the hosts will need an OS either Linux or Windows so it can run the TensorFlow Lite APIs.

Would it be possible to host it using microcontroller which is a bare metal without OS? Anyone tried before?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you talking about USB Accelerator module ? If yes, then it needs to fulfil these requirements : https://coral.ai/docs/accelerator/get-started/#requirements

Comment: Not the USB accelerator module. I would like to develop a customised PCB with Coral chip and a microcontroller ARM Cortex M4 (e.g. STM32L4) . Would it be possible to have a microcontroller host?